# Use both InstrumentationTestRunner and AndroidJUnitRunner with Robotium and Espresso

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, robotium, android-espresso

We're using Robotium with the `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner` for our tests. Nevertheless we want to replace Robotium for Espresso, but we still have some doubts about it, since we have a machine with Jenkins for the CI.

Espresso uses the `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` while Robotium uses the aforementioned and first, we would like to be able to use both testing frameworks at the same time.
Is it possible? How can we specify that in the `build.gradle` file? How can we configure our jenkins machine to have different jobs for the different testing frameworks?

I understand it is possible to have Espresso extend the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, since our Robotium test classes also use a test runner which extends from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, but we still need to tackle the problem of the instrumentation test runner.

Comment: May I know how did you solve your problem? I have this issue, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Android developer docs, `AndroidJUnitRunner` replaces the older `InstrumentationTestRunner` and enables JUnit 4 tests.

> The `AndroidJUnitRunner` class is a `JUnit` test runner that lets you run `JUnit 3` or `JUnit 4`-style test classes on Android devices, including those using the `Espresso` and `UI Automator` testing frameworks.
>
> The test runner handles loading your test package and the app under test to a device, running your tests, and reporting test results. This class replaces the `InstrumentationTestRunner` class, which only supports JUnit 3 tests.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html

I've not found many examples of being able to run Instrumentation Tests (e.g. using Robotium). I've been looking for my own purposes.

The doc explains how to replace the test runner in your `build.gradle` file https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests